# Can I automate PhpMyAdmin Export to file by URL ($_GET)?

Tags: url, phpmyadmin, export

I would like to automate export of a database to a file, using an external cronjob service that can only 'surf' to an URL. I tried to make a PHP script to execute mysqldump, but my provider disabled php exec. Is there a way to format URL to automate export to a file on the server?
E.G.  `http://www.example.com/phpmyadmin/export.php?db=databasename&fn=filename&type=sql` (or something likewise)

Answer (score 0):

No, phpMyAdmin is meant be used interactively by an administrator and doesn't expose functionality like this to be called by a script.

I've never used it, don't know anything about it, and can't help you if it causes problems — but https://github.com/ifsnop/mysqldump-php looks like exactly what you're after.